# Changing active class when clicking on new page without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, jinja2

I am implementing a flask app with Jinja templating, and I am trying to add an active class to one of my nav anchor elements at a time, based on which URL the user is currently on. However, this is only working when I load the home page or refresh any page, but not when I click a different page.

I have tried many approaches using plain JavaScript, jQuery, and jinja templating to solve this issue, but all of them produced the same result that I have mentioned.

Here's my application.py file

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
   return render_template("index.html", page="")


@app.route("/AboutUs")
   def about():
   return render_template("about.html")


@app.route("/Services")
def services():
   return render_template("services.html")
```

Here's code for the navigation menu in my layout html template:

```
<div class="navbar-nav mx-auto" id="menu">
  <a {% if request.path == '/' %}class="active nav-link"{% endif %}
  class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
  <a {% if request.path == '/AboutUs' %}class="active nav-link"{% endif %}
  class="nav-link" href="/AboutUs">About Us</a>
  <a {% if request.path == '/Services' %}class="active nav-link"{% endif %}
  class="nav-link" href="/Services">Our Services</a>
</div>
```

Could someone direct me to where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project i have use below code to make it work . You can just check if the `path` given has in `request.path` or not depending on this add active .   i.e :

```
  <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto" id="menu">
      <a {% if request.path == '/' %}
            class="active nav-link"
         {% else %}
            class="nav-link"
         {% endif %}
        href="/">Home</a>
      <a {% if '/AboutUs' in request.path %}
          class="active nav-link" 
        {% else %}
         class="nav-link"
        {% endif %} 
        href="/AboutUs">About Us</a>
      <a {% if '/Services' in request.path  %}
         class="active nav-link" 
        {% else %}
      class="nav-link"
        {% endif %} href="/Services">Our Services</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've tried this and I still get the same result - the active link only changes if I refresh the page but not when I click the link. I tried removing my swup transitions and now it works! Any idea how to get it to work while keeping the transitions? The transition  am using is a fade transition, with changing opacity and a transform from left to right.

Comment: I am not sure about that ..you can ask another question for same :) .

Answer (score 0):

When comparing falsy in JavaScript if returns always false if there is a special character. I think "/" is one of these characters. You can do "string".trim() on both strings to fix this, or use === in steafdof ==

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean, can you explain it a little bit more? Sorry I am a new programmer :(

Answer (score 0):

A little late but maybe it will be useful to someone

`{% set active_page = 'services' %}`

`<a href="#" class=" {{'active' if active_page =='services' else '' }}">Services</a>`